# Why doesn't ufw enforce firewall rules for traffic coming from Virtualbox VM

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, nmap, ufw

I've been running Linux Mint 17 on my laptop for a while and thought I had it locked down to not allow any incoming traffic through "Firewall Configuration" (ufw GUI)—I have also validated this from my laptop and other hosts on the network.

Today I noticed however that when playing around with `nmap` from a VirtualBox VM running Kali Linux that the VM can acess all open ports on the laptop WLAN IP if going through VirtualBox's NAT Network. NMAP neatly lists all open ports and I can `ssh` to my laptop.

Any ideas on what could enable the Virtual machine to bypass the firewall? Any workarounds?

Comment: How are you configuring the NICs on the guest (bridged, nated, internal network)?. What NICs do you have on the host and how are they assigned inside the firewall? Keep in mind that accessing the firewall from a given zone is just that, doesn't matter if you target one interface or the other, just where the packet originates.